# Spring Cloud Stream Source returning a reactive Flux<>?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to have a Spring Cloud Stream Source that outputs a reactive Flux (from the Project Reactor). 
In my pom.xml, `spring-cloud-stream-reactive` and `reactor-core` are imported as dependencies.
And I have declared the following code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class SensorDataSourceApplication {

   @StreamListener
   @Output(Source.OUTPUT)
   public Flux<String> emitPolling() {
     return Flux.intervalMillis(5000)
                .log()
                .map(l -> "Hello World!!")
                .log()
                ;
   }
}
```

But I don't get anything in my processor or sink. All examples I've found are related to `Processor`. So, I was wondering whether it is possible to do something like that for a `Source`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@StreamListener` is by its nature intended to be used for Sinks and Processors.

I've added https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/722 to track this requirement.

Comment: You mean Processors and Sinks :)
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you think it's feasible to use reactive library to build a source without using `@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "10"))`?
I mean, may be, something that needs more coding effort than adding some annotations.

Comment: `@InboundChannelAdapter` writes directly to the channel - you can use that if you want but it is a distinct implementation.

Comment: To the other question - I don't see benefits for a reactive polling source, but I do see some for a source using a reactive API for interacting with a database, or some other data source for example. So, yes, but perhaps this use case is contrived.